# Remove character from String c++/Arduino UNO

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, erase

I need to delete some characters from string. When i used erase it doesn`t work, compilation error erase no member named. Please help me. Probaly it is because I writing for Arduino UNO.

Comment: Maybe in Arduino they have different function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) class is quite different from [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). For example `erase` doesn't exists. But there is method [`remove`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringRemove).

Anyway, you should start with: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what KIIV suggested, you could possibly do something like this:

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    String words = "This   is a sentence."; //reassign same string at the start of loop.
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(words);
    char c;
    char no = ' '; //character I want removed.

    for (int i=0; i<words.length()-1;++i){
        c = words.charAt(i);
        if(c==no){
            words.remove(i, 1);
        }
    }
    Serial.println(words);
    delay(5000);//5 second delay, for demo purposes.
}
```

Comment: Just be aware of fact, that remove with one parameter removes rest of string too. If you want to remove only one character, you have to use variant with two parameters. And it might be indexed from 1, not from 0;

Comment: @KIIV Thanks! Corrected

Comment: @KIIV How do you tell if it's indexed from `1` and not `0`?

Comment: Tested, it's indexed from 0, I've just overlooked something.. However your code is not working.

Comment: @KIIV I don't have an Arduino on me at the moment to correct - but I'll be able to test and correct it later today. Thanks again

Comment: I've eddited your code and added test case when it fails :) It fails on multiple occurencies of the character to remove. As it's checking i+1 but the whole string was moved to current position.

Comment: @KIIV I see that, thanks for the help! Hopefully this get the OP on the right track.

Comment: Thanks now I understand logic)

Answer (score -1):

The Libraries in Arduino are customized in order to factor the memory constraints of the target Micro controller. For example , the Uno runs on a mega328P Atmel (now Microchip) device, which has only has 32 KB flash memory.

Comment: So how to use remove function?